# Trying to have three actions occur via jquery and javascript on a wordpress page. All fire in firefox, but not in chrome or safari

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, wordpress, callback

I've tried this a bunch of different ways, and the only way that kind of works is as follows.

I have a jQuery.click handler occuring on page click, and a jQuery.submit handler on submission.  The form itself is a post to google payments.  Again, as I have it works just fine in firefox, but no luck at all in chrome or safari.  Maybe I'm completely missing something here.  I've researched Jquerys documentation and looked around quite a bit and still have nothing on what the issue could be.  Is what I'm doing just wrong or not possible?  (I have also attempted to have the submit handler call a js function holding the window open info.)  I also wanted to have field validation but including that just breaks the whole thing down in firefox as well.  Any ideas would be great.

```
jQuery('#submission_button').click(function()
{
var download_id=document.getElementById("the_download").value;
if (download_id=="1") window.open("http://www.blahblahblah.com/something1.pdf",'Download');
if (download_id=="2") window.open("http://www.blahblahblah.com/something2.pdf",'Download');
}


jQuery('#myform').submit(function() 
{ 
var downloaditem = document.getElementById("the_download");
var thedownloaditem = downloaditem.options[downloaditem.selectedIndex].text;
var data = {
    action: 'mail_before_submit',
    firstname: document.getElementById('first').value,
    lastname: document.getElementById('last').value,
    address: document.getElementById('address').value,
    city: document.getElementById('city').value,
    state: document.getElementById('state').value,
    zip: document.getElementById('zip').value,
    phone: document.getElementById('phonenumber').value,
    email: document.getElementById('email').value,
    thedownload: thedownloaditem,
    donationamt: document.getElementById('somepricefield').value,
    _ajax_nonce: <?php echo wp_create_nonce( 'my_email_ajax_nonce' ); ?>
};
jQuery.post("http://www.myurlforwordpress.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
        //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
});
this.submit();
});
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing both a post and a submit at the same time?  Do you realize that the post has just been started when you then call submit which looks like it will just again do a post.

Comment: This was the specific advice I was following for the wp_mail hook for wordpress:  http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/18845/wp-mail-script-with-jquery-post

Comment: Could you check if Chrome console caught any JS errors for starters?
Right-click, inspect element, then press "Esc" to bring up the console.

Comment: Looks like I'm getting an uncaught syntax error  for unexpected token ?  It's being thrown from the _ajax_nonce line.  Going to see if I perhaps I can pull that out of the data var.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code which fixes several issues:

1. Fixes syntax error in nonce line (makes up a random number because it isn't clear what this is supposed to be).
2. Removes the .submit() function entirely.  If you're trying to to an ajax call on a button click it is not needed and is complicating things.
3. Cleans up the organization of the code.

Since I can't run this code, I can't promise there are no more syntax errors, but it should be going in the right direction.

Here's the code:

```
jQuery('#submission_button').click(function() {
    var download_id=document.getElementById("the_download").value;
    if (download_id=="1") window.open("http://www.blahblahblah.com/something1.pdf",'Download');
    if (download_id=="2") window.open("http://www.blahblahblah.com/something2.pdf",'Download');

    var downloaditem = document.getElementById("the_download");
    var thedownloaditem = downloaditem.options[downloaditem.selectedIndex].text;
    var data = {
        action: 'mail_before_submit',
        firstname: document.getElementById('first').value,
        lastname: document.getElementById('last').value,
        address: document.getElementById('address').value,
        city: document.getElementById('city').value,
        state: document.getElementById('state').value,
        zip: document.getElementById('zip').value,
        phone: document.getElementById('phonenumber').value,
        email: document.getElementById('email').value,
        thedownload: thedownloaditem,
        donationamt: document.getElementById('somepricefield').value,
        _ajax_nonce: "my_email_ajax_nonce" + Date.now()
    };
    jQuery.post("http://www.myurlforwordpress.org/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", data, function(response) {
        //alert('Got this from the server: ' + response);
    });
});
```

Comment: Pretty close, for some reason the semicolon at the end of Date.now() had to go, and I actually need the default submission to happen on the form post, so I just removed the return(false), so that the post to google fires.  The download triggers on all browsers now, and the post to google goes through, but the email only fires in firefox, but this is much closer then I was an hour ago, so thanks a bunch for at least getting me in a better direction.

Comment: Simplified it even more so there's just a post happening from a button click and there's no submit involved.

Comment: Good catch on the semi-colon.  I don't know what you mean by "the email only fires".  Is that something that is supposed to be happening on the server?

Comment: That jQuery post is a call to a function that calls wp_mail from the server.  So it should be firing right at that post, but for some reason it only happens in firefox, not in chrome or safari.  Haven't tried IE so unsure of how that will pan out.

Comment: I'd suggest looking at server logs or traces to find out why it isn't sending the email then.  It could be something wrong with the prep of the data on the client side or it could be all on the server side - but the next answer is probably on the server side.

Comment: Checking now but I'll probably have to finish tomorrow, thanks for the head start.